# Laravel query with complex DB schema

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

**Task** (short): Create query for job seekers, that have **lacking** documents

#### Entities and important fields

1. Jobseeker (id),
2. Profession (id, jobseeker_id),
3. Appointment (id, jobseeker_id, profession_id, location_id, employer_id),
4. Document (id, jobseeker_id, document_category_id),
5. DocumentCategory (id, name)
6. Location (id)
7. Employer (id)

#### Relations

1. Jobseeker hasMany Professions (jobseeker_id)
2. Jobseeker hasMany Appointments (jobseeker_id)
3. Jobseeker hasMany Documents (jobseeker_id)
4. Profession hasMany Appointments (profession_id)
5. Document (document_category_id) belongsTo DocumentCategory
6. Appointment belongsTo Employer (employer_id)
7. Appointment belongsTo Location (location_id)
8. DocumentCategory hasMany Employers (many to many)
9. DocumentCategory hasMany Locations (many to many)

#### Description (simplified)

Jobseeker has main Profession which is last
Jobseeker has main Appointment which is the last appointment for the last profession

Jobseeker is required to have documents of certain DocumentCategory,
which can be found via his/her main Appointment the folowing way:

1. DocumentCategory->employers should contain **main** Appointment->employer
2. DocumentCategory->locations should contain **main** Appointment->location

If this statements are true, then the DocumentCategory is required
else the documents of this DocumentCategory are **lacking**

#### The question/problem (extended)

I should make two queries to DB:

1. Fetch all jobseekers which have at least one **lacking** documentCategory (They have zero docs of at least one **required** category)
2. Fetch all jobseekers which have certain documentCategory **lacking**. (When the documentCategory name is given)

This should be queries, I can not post-process to filter retrieved data, because the whole task is within a context, where couple of queries (together with mine) are applied one by one to filter specific jobseekers.

#### Things I've tried

1. For specific name:

   ```
   $jobseekers = Jobseeker
       ::whereDoesntHave('documents', function($query) use($documentCategoryName) {
           $query->whereHas('documentCategory', function ($query) use ($documentCategoryName) {
               $query->whereName($documentCategoryName);
           });
       });
   ```

   I guess I should select all jobseekers, which have particular documentCategory as **required** and inner join them with above query somehow to filter, but can not yet understand how to do it, because it's hard to select main appointment by query.
2. If the name is not given and we fetch jobseekers, which **lack** documents for at least one of any categories, I'm stuck here also. We can not use whereDoesntHave, because if jobseeker has at least one **required** documentCategory, he will not be fetched or at least there should be some workaround which I don't know yet.

#### PS

The whole system of relations and scopes is quite big. The architecture is quite complex and inconvenient to work via SQL. I tried to skip odd information as much as possible for my question, please ask if there is something I described insufficiently or unclear. Thank you!

Comment: this seems too complicated. it is hard to explain, hard to understand and will be hard (guess: nightmare) to maintain - my guess would be that this structure lacks good design. 
Eloquent & its relations are really cool for small & simple stuff. Once things get more complex I don't use it at all, but rather go for query builder (joins, subqueries and whatever it takes) or even raw query - it depends.
I would love to help you out, but I don't understand it really... you may write in in pseudo code, then we can try to sort it out